# How to access the tag name in svn pre-commit hook

Tags: svn, hook, svn-hooks

I have a list of tags that cannot be changed and was wanting to implement a pre-commit hook that will check my list to make sure that none of the files being changed are in any of the immutable tags.

It seems I only have access to the revision number and path to the repo in the `pre-commit` script. How can I check against my tag list to see if any files being committed are in one of the listed tags? Basically I need to make sure that any commits of files that have a `tags/TagInList/` prefix will be denied, where I would run something like:

```
 grep 'tagOnCommitFile' /path/to/tagListFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check output of `svnlook dirs-changed PATH-TO-REPO`.

Sample output against revision, in your case - transaction

```
>svnlook dirs-changed -r 4 /Repo

branches/MyFixes/
branches/MyFixes/Data/
branches/MyFixes/NewData/
```